# Ansible on AWS, not able to use private keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have been trying to use Ansible over AWS.

I am using ppk file to login to  AWS. I want to use the same with Ansible.

This ppk file was extracted from pem file which i got from AWS.

This is the command i am using.

```
ansible all -m ping -u ubuntu --private-key /opt/keys/privateKey.ppk
```

I get the following

```
Enter passphrase for key '/opt/keys/privateKey.ppk
172.31.50.XX | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey).
    while connecting to 172.31.50.XX:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

I did not create the keys with a passphase so not sure why I am getting this error

Comment: Ansible uses OpenSSH under the covers so you'll need to use the original pem file that AWS generated for you.

Comment: worked. with pem file. There was a refernce of ppk file in hosts file which i had to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible uses OpenSSH under the covers so you'll need to use the original pem file that AWS generated for you.

Comment: I have some concerns around keeping pem file in the machine . Is it not a security risk ? How do you keep it safe ?

Comment: You could always passphrase the private key. Or encrypt it with Ansible Vault or any number of other encryption methods